# Regarding GDI Mapping in my Textbook example

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

This is a snippet of an example in my book. What I don't understand in this code is that the SetWindowOrgEx x value increases positively to the left, why is this? Tehinically this should be like MM_TEXT in which the x value increases going to the right. I notice as well that the x value does increase to the right with SetViewportOrgEx. Why does the x value increase to the right with SetViewportOrgEx but SetWindowOrgEx's x value increases to the left? Also, what's the point of changing both extents? Couldn't you just edit one of the extents?

```
SetMapMode(hdc, MM_ISOTROPIC);
SetWindowExtEx(hdc, 276, 72, NULL);
SetViewportExtEx(hdc, cxClient, cyClient, NULL);

SetWindowOrgEx(hdc, 138, 36, NULL);
SetViewportOrgEx(hdc, cxClient / 2, cyClient / 2, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you're doing, but these functions are used to shift the axis, so the logical point (0, 0) refers to something other than the upper-left corner.

You generally should only be using one functions, `SetWindowOrgEx` and `SetViewportOrgEx`, depending on which suits your needs; not both.

Comment: I know what the basis of the setOrg functions but I don't understand why the x values are increasing in opposite directions in the setOrg functions in my example. When I do SetWindowOrgEx(hdc, 138 + 100, 36, NULL); the +100 will make it go 100 units to the left but if I put +100 in the SetViewportOrgEx instead as so: SetViewportOrgEx(hdc, (cxClient / 2) + 100, cyClient / 2, NULL); it will make it go +100 units to the right. I don't understand why the setOrg functions are not consistent with eachother.